# UseMethod common tasks all S3 classes

Tags: r

I am using S3 methods in that way.
First, seek all commonn task between all classes programmed and put this code only once **before** "Usemethod". Then, I program the rest of each class.
The problem arises when you modify an argument, because they are defined by-reference. Other tasks like check arguments or define sub-functions works well in these schemas.

The next example, I modify an argument:

```
secure_filter <- function(table, col, value){
  if(!is.numeric(table[[col]])) table[[col]] <- as.numeric(table[[col]])
  message("converting to numeric")
  print(str(table))
  UseMethod("secure_filter", table)
}

secure_filter.data.table <- function(
  table, col, value
){
  return(table[ col == value,]) 
}

secure_filter.data.frame <- function(
  table, col, value
){
  return(table[table$col == !!value,])
}
```

and the result is wrong

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("a", "b", "c"), column = c("1", "2", "3"))
dt <- as.data.table(df)

> secure_filter(dt, "column", 1)
converting to numeric
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a     : chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ column: num  1 2 3
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
NULL
Empty data.table (0 rows and 2 cols): a,column

> secure_filter(df, "column", 1)
converting to numeric
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a     : chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ column: num  1 2 3
NULL
[1] a      column
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

*Am I using S3 well? How do I save repeated code between S3 classes?*

Any example in a well known R function?

I am using this approach to re-program tidyverse scripts to data.table scripts.

Comment: `subset(df, get("column") == 1)` and `df[df[["column"]] == 1, ]` each work for both data frames and data table so S3 is not really needed in the example.

Comment: Sorry, but i've done a silly example to hide a bigger problem i have. My question is if can i avoid repeat code. And if you can, propose other approach to solve the same task by data.table or by tidyverse (not a filter only, an undefined task)

Comment: One possibility is to create a function with the repeated code and call it from each method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NextMethod` instead `UseMethod`.

```
secure_filter <- function(table, col, value){
  if(!is.numeric(table[[col]])) table[[col]] <- as.numeric(table[[col]])
  message("converting to numeric")
  print(str(table))
  NextMethod("secure_filter")
  #UseMethod("secure_filter", table)
}


> secure_filter(dt, "column", 1)
converting to numeric
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a     : chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ column: num  1 2 3
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
NULL
   a column
1: a      1
> secure_filter(df, "column", 1)
converting to numeric
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a     : chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ column: num  1 2 3
NULL
  a column
1 a      1
```

But I don´t know that answer is well behaved because it doesn't shot the dispatched method neither get the generic.

```
> sloop::s3_dispatch(secure_filter(dt, "column", 1))
   secure_filter.data.table
   secure_filter.data.frame
   secure_filter.default
> sloop::s3_get_method(secure_filter)
Error: Could not find generic
```

Comment: It solves the example, but not my real problem. It gets "S3 NextMethod called from anonimous function". Maybe because my generic function belongs to "function" class and not "generic" class. I do not know how to escape from this, so I used @G. Grothendieck suggestion (make more function for repeated code).